# va_args and 64 bits

Tags: c++, linux, 64-bit, printf

I'm the lead dev for [Bitfighter](http://bitfighter.org), and am having problems porting the game to 64-bit Linux.  This should be a relatively easy and common problem, but it has stumped a number of people and I have been able to find no good information about it.

[[ The code compiles in 32-bit with gcc version 4.1.2, and others, and fails with several variants of 64-bit Linux, but I am relying on reports from others, and do not have the exact version of gcc that is failing.  But it is failing for several people, on a variety of Linux flavors.  I am 99% sure this is not a compiler version issue. ]]

I have the following:

```
 void UserInterface::drawCenteredString(int y, int size, const char *format, ...)
   {
    va_list args; 
    va_start(args, format); 
    char buffer[2048]; 
    dVsprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), format, args); 
    va_end(args);

    drawCenteredString2(y, size, buffer);
 }   

 // Elsewhere, in platform.cpp... (this is where the error occurs)

 S32 dVsprintf(char *buffer, int bufferSize, const char *format, void *arglist)
 {
    return vsnprintf(buffer, bufferSize, format, (char *) arglist);
 }
```

This works great on 32-bit platforms.  However, when I compile it on 64-bit Linux, it fails:

```
 platform.cpp:457: error: cannot convert 'char*' to '__va_list_tag*' for argument '4' to 'int TNL::vsnprintf(char*, size_t, const char*, __va_list_tag*)'
```

I've tried many variants, including:

```
return vsnprintf(buffer, bufferSize, format, (va_list) arglist);
```

without success.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to make this construct portable, or achieve the same ends with a more 64-bit friendly mechanism?

And, for bonus points :-) can anyone tell me where the va_list_tag thingy comes from?

Thanks!

============================================

Here is the solution we settled on, using a different example:

```
logprintf("Hello %s", name);
```

calls

```
void logprintf(const char *format, ...)
{
   va_list s;    
   va_start( s, format );

   logger(LogConsumer::GeneralFilter, format, s);
   va_end(s);
}
```

calls

```
void logger(LogConsumer::FilterType filtertype, const char *format, va_list args)
{
   char buffer[4096];

   vsnprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), format, args);

   Platform::outputDebugString(buffer);
}
```

Comment: Could you please add information indicating which line it is, where the error occurs? Inside UserInterface::drawCenteredString or inside dVsprintf? Also please add, what compiler (exact version) and what OS (which linux) you use.

Comment: I modified the question to clarify that the error occurs where dVsprintf() is defined.

Comment: on some 64-bit implementations `va_list` isn't just pointer to the stack like it is with usual x86 C calling conventions. This is because the first few args are passed via registers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change

```
S32 dVsprintf(char *buffer, int bufferSize, const char *format, void *arglist)
```

to

```
S32 dVsprintf(char *buffer, size_t bufferSize, const char *format, va_list arglist)
```

and it should work without the cast.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, the prototype for your dVsprintf is wrong.

```
S32 dVsprintf(char *buffer, int bufferSize, const char *format, void *arglist)
```

arglist clearly has the type `va_list` from context.

Secondly, why not just use `vsnprintf` instead of calling `dVsprintf`?

Thirdly, your function drawCenteredString clearly infinitely recurses, which is not good:

```
void UserInterface::drawCenteredString(int y, int size, const char *format, ...)
{
    ///...
    drawCenteredString(y, size, buffer);
}
```

---

`__va_list_tag*` must be the underlying type of va_list.  This is hard to verify, since va_list is gcc implementation dependent, and is not defined in the system header files, as far as I can see.

Comment: Yes, it apparently does!  That's a result of my attempts to simplify the problem a bit, and remove extraneous code.  It doesn't really recurse forever!  :-)

Comment: I don't call vsnprintf directly because I'm using a slightly different implementation for Windows, and in my production code, the dVsprintf function has an #ifdef that uses a different function for each platform.  That said, I might be able to make dVsprintf into a macro and avoid the extra function call.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
S32 dVsprintf(char *buffer, int bufferSize, const char *format, ...)
{
    va_list va_args;
    va_start( va_args, format );
    S32 result = vsnprintf(buffer, bufferSize, format, va_args); 
    va_end( va_args );
    return result;
}
```

`__va_list_tag*` is the hidden implementation type of `...`, that's why it didn't like the `char*` typecast -- suddenly the pointer wasn't 32 bit anymore...

Considering this is C++, have you considered a more C++ approach than va_args? Several ideas come to mind:

- use [streams](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/) and `<<` operator to do formating
- use a vector of [boost::variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/html/variant.html) or [boost::any](http://www.boost.org/doc/html/any.html)
- use a recursive [tuple](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/libs/tuple/doc/tuple_users_guide.html) printer
- use [boost::format](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/format)

Answer (score 0):

In my case renaming the stdarg.h in out...osprey/obj/include, to fix_starg.h, soved to issue,and of course the header that requires stdarg.h also needs to be edited to:  #include .  Apparently stdarg.h sitting in out...kernel/obj/include was creating a conflict in bionic.  I've noticed this issue with a few header files (particuarily types.h and similar variations).  The headers seem to be fine in kernel/include and in bionic but as soon as the are in kernel/obj/incudes or kernel/obj/includes/linux, it seems to create an issue.  I guess this folder is processed differently, at least it seemed to create havoc in bionic.  Renaming the header files seemed to solve the issue.